# Why is this SQL updating the entire table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been hit by the classic beginner mistake.  As if I'd done an UPDATE with no WHERE clause.

Here's the SQL:

```
"UPDATE teams SET description = ? " +
"FROM teams t " +
"JOIN team_memberships tm ON t.id = tm.team_id " +
"JOIN users u ON tm.user_id = u.id " + 
"WHERE t.id = ? AND u.uid = ?";
```

And despite the WHERE t.id = ? the SQL still updates the entire table.

... Can you see the problem?

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: What parameters are you setting?

Comment: It updates the entire table.  The parameters are correct.

Comment: There is no relation between "teams" (not the alias "t" !!) and the rest. Whatever the rest will do, all records in "teams" must be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
UPDATE teams AS t
SET description = ? 
FROM  team_memberships tm 
      JOIN users u ON tm.user_id = u.id 
WHERE t.id = tm.team_id AND
      t.id = ? AND u.uid = ?
```

*please do backup your db first before executing the statement above*

Comment: Tip: No need to backup, just open a transaction and never commit (roll it back after doing some selects to check what was changed by the update).

Comment: Wow you just blew my mind.  Very cool.  And I got a chuckle out of the 'please do backup'.  ;)  Oh, and this worked.  You're awesome!

Comment: I looked at the documentation here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html and found out that it's a bit different syntax frm `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

Run your query with select statement.
You will see it will return all values.

Use left join with first join and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work, same problem